# invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run an anova model in R. I have a data file which contains 3 rows and 12 columns. Each row is data for a particular level of the explanatory variable. Cell [i,j] is the j'th response for level i. The file is ".dat" extension. I am running the following R code to try to get a 36 by 2 data frame to run the anova model instead of the 3 by 12 original data frame:

```
data <- read.table("usedcar.dat", row.names = 1)
young <- data[1,]
med <- data[2,]
old <- data[3,]
Price <- c(young, med, old)
Age <- as.factor(c(rep(1,12), rep(2,12), rep(3,12)))
data <- cbind(Age, Price)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

But when I try to get the anova model out of it I get the invalid list type error:

```
m1 <- aov(Price ~ Age, data = data)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Price ~ Age, data = data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'Price'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a random matrix if that will help:

```
replicate(12, rnorm(3))
```

Here is the str(data) result:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Age  :List of 36
  ..$ 1 : int 1
  ..$ 2 : int 1
  ..$ 3 : int 1
  ...
  ..$ 36: int 3
 $ Price:List of 36
  ..$ 1 : int 2300
  ...
  ..$ 36: int 2075
```

Comment: Could you please include the exact error message?

Comment: It would also help to make your example reproducable, i.e. include a small dataset which generates the error

Comment: If you're supplying a `data` parameter to a model, you shouldn't subset (`$`) in the formula: `aov(Price ~ Age, data = data)`

Comment: same error with aov(Price~Age,data=data) :(

Comment: Given the error, I'd look at `str(data)`; your chopping seems to have left `Price` as a list column.

Comment: Don't use `cbind/as.data.frame`, use `data <- data.frame(Age, Price)`.

Comment: @Rui If I use data<-data.frame(Age,Price) I get a 36X36 data frame...

Comment: @alistaire that does seem to be the problem, but why? also how do I correct?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**tl;dr** rows of data frames are lists, not numeric vectors. When you `read.table()` you get a data frame (so constructing a matrix, as I did before, doesn't replicate the problem).

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=3))
young <- data[1,]; med <- data[2,]; old <- data[3,]
Price <- c(young, med, old)
str(Price)
## ## List of 36
## ##  $ V1 : num 0.648
## ##  $ V2 : num 0.157
## ## ...
```

The fact that this is a list, not a numeric vector, is a problem.
There are a variety of ways of handling this.  The easiest is `unlist()`:

```
dd <- data.frame(Age,Price=unlist(Price))
aov(Price~Age,dd)
```

Comment: I think that the problem has something to do with the fact that I'm reading the data in as a data frame from a .dat file?

Comment: `unlist()` may need to be applied to each column separately. When I applied it to the whole data frame, it turned the data frame into one long vector.

Answer (score 8):

The error message `invalid type (list) for variable x` from the `lm` or other formula-based functions generally indicates that variable `x` is expecting a vector, but instead is a list. A standard model for debugging the error is to examine the result of `str(data_frame_name$x)` (where `data_frame_name` is the data frame that contains x). Usually, you would find that `x` is not quite the data type that you expect.