# Weird error I cannot get around in R for Random Forests

Tags: r, random-forest

I am running a Random Forest on my text classification project. I have created unigrams and I am trying to run the Random forest. Every time I try to run it, I am hit by this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(terms(reformulate(attributes(Terms)$term.labels)), : invalid type (special) for variable 'break'
```

I guess it means that 'break' is a special type but how do I go around this? I cant really run my model at all because of this :/

Comment: `break` is a reserved flow control word, that might lead to difficulties used otherwise. This would be an otherwise. Renaming looks advised.

Comment: @Chris yes I realized that as well! but I don't think I can change it seeing as it is a feature for my text classification problem. I did try changing it but an error got thrown again

Comment: Might we rather be in [this sort of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126735/invalid-type-list-for-variable)? This seems to speak to how to resolve.

Comment: please post some reproducible example or `dput` you data